# Symfony3 con NetBeans 8.0 es posible?

Tags: netbeans, symfony3, symfony, netbeans-8.0

Actualmente uso `NetBeans` para desarrollar con `Symfony2` y quiero actualizarme a `Symfony3`. Mi conexión a internet solo me permite descargar archivos de pocos megas, por lo que en este momento no puedo descargar ningún IDE. La versión mas reciente que tengo de `NetBeans` es la 8.0 y mi pregunta es:

¿Es posible desarrollar en `Symfony3` usando `NetBeans 8.0`?

Nota: Pongo esta pregunta aquí porque ya he buscado en google y no he encontrado respuesta. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Gracias @Luiggi por la nueva etiqueta! :)

Comment: parece que sí y no a la vez. Si no actualizas netbeans no tendrás soporte al 100% pero si miras este link: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257708 verás que si cambias las dependencias puedes más o menos trabajar con él.

Comment: Apache netbeans ha sdo liberado al open source como un IDE únicamente para Java, por lo que no será posible por mucho tiempo correr proyectos de node y php, les aviso si algo cambia. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Como te comenta el compañero, para Sf 3.x el soporte de NetBeans parece que no está completo.

Personalmente, te recomendaría probar PhpStorm; verás que merece, y mucho, la pena.

Un saludo.

Comment: Así es. Gracias!